# Outlier transformation for t-test

Tags: t-test, outliers

In a normally distributed sample with one outlier, some suggest changing the value of the outlier to be one unit above the next highest score.

1. If you are doing a comparison test on two groups using the t-test, do you change the score of your outlier to the second highest score out of all the data or for the second highest score of the same group?
2. What is one unit higher than $3.58$, $3.59$ or $4.58$?
3. What do you do if your outlier is $5$ and your second highest value is $4$?

Comment: Note that you are referring to a form of [winsorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing).

Comment: Is winsorising always done with a specific % in mind like in the artcile you linked? Is there a rule of quartile that you should use like it that article below 5 and higher than 95 ?

Comment: It can be done different ways. The most basic is to make the 'outliers' *equal to* the most extreme non-outlier values (rather than +1).

Comment: I finaly found the answere for the question 2 and 3 but not the answere to the first question. You can change for the same score, but if you want them to keep there rank in the distribution you can give a +1 or +0.1 to the second highest score. Still don't know do if you use the highest score of the same group or all the sample.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.